ngx-owl-carousel-o in angular 14 JS error
I use owl carousel 14.0.1 in angular 14 and when touch drag, i get this error in production not localhost:

more detail:

my owl option is:
customOptions: OwlOptions = {
loop: true,
mouseDrag: true,
touchDrag: true,
pullDrag: false,
dots: true,
navSpeed: 600,
autoplay: true,
autoplayTimeout: 3000,
rtl: true,
lazyLoad: true,
items: 1,
nav: false
};


please share minimal reproducible example
